# Ошибка при подключении к БД MYSQL

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите насколько влияет то, что у нас указано в class. Как правильно выбрать нужный?

Ошибку вот такую выдаёт при тестовом подключении: [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.

Скачал отсюда драйвер: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.31. Установил как библиотеку и загрузил, можно посмотреть на картинке. Мне нужен именно он, потому что в более поздних версиях нет метода: FabricMySQLDriver();

Данные все прописываю, ошибку можно увидеть на скриншоте.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В maven прописал.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.31</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы версию mysql правильно указали? Обычно такие ошибки выдает в случае ошибок в maven: название, версия зависимости и тд. Скачанные файлы можно ложить куда угодно, главное путь к ним указать в Идее.

Comment: Mysql сервер установлен? База создана? Логин и пароль к этой базе прописаны в Идее?

Comment: База и Идея на одном компе стоят? Неплохо бы название БД указать, к которой вы устанавливаете соединение. На сервере конект открыт для вашего пк? Сервер и пк в одной локальной сети?

Comment: Нет, база серверная.

Comment: У вас мускуль не принимает соединения. Вообще не слушает на 0.0.0.0:3306. Либо он не запущен, либо не сконфигурирован (скорее всего, т.к. это его дефолтная конфигурация).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка 08001 возникает в случае, когда версия mysql, установленная на сервере, не соответствует версии, из которой устанавливается коннект к серверу, то есть Вашей версии mysql-connector.

Определитесь с версией на сервере и скачайте соответствующую версию коннектора. Также создайте БД и пропишите ее название в настройках соединения.

Детальнее можно почитать тут: https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-mysql-jdbc-08001-database-connection-error/

Совместимость mysql-connector с версиями mysql server: connector 5.1(во всех случаях у вас должен быть установлен jre 1.8) - server 5.6; 5.7; 8.0. Connector 8.0 - server 5.6; 5.7; 8.0.
Ссылка на оригинал:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, на сервере стоит версия 5.7.25, но при добавлении в зависимости Maven найти не может, также на сайте скачать нельзя: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.7.25

Comment: Какая версия будет с ней совместима, а то что-то не понимаю, вот тут: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java можно посмотреть список, 5.7.25 - это ICM , но даже не сталкивался с таким, что это означает? Это означает, что версия для сервера ? А какую тогда поставить можно мне, чтобы можно было пользоваться и чтобы был метод FabricMySQLDriver();.

Comment: 5.1.6 попробуйте